# Writing a script to look for a folder and run a batch file in it

Tags: batch-file

I have a really messy program in my environment that basically has a jump client on over 7000 machines in my environment. When I upgrade the appliance that the jump client talks to it starts an in place upgrade but if there are computers off or off the network obviously the upgrade times out. Problem is, I cant mass deploy the updated jump client because the previous version has to be uninstalled first.

WMIC uninstaller doesn't work, msiexec uninstaller doesn't work. There is a batch file built into the program stored at %ProgramData%\ClientNameRandomNumbers. Problem is, you can also install a dissolvable client in the moment if needed and everytime the dissolvable client installs, it doesn't clean up after itself. So you have random folders that may or may not be the one that contains the uninstall.bat batch file that I need to run. I wanted to write a script to mass deploy that will start that batch file on each computer but I am having problems.

Basically I want it to search for the folder with a wild card, if it finds it CD to that directory and then try to run the uninstall, if it can't find the uninstall, continue through to deleting the folder as it is an old shell folder. And then go back and look for more folders until it can't find anymore and then go to exit.

This is what I have:

```
:START
cd %programdata%\bomgar-scc* || IF ERRORLEVEL not = 0 GOTO END

start uninstall.bat /Wait || cd c:\programdata && 
rd C:\programdata\bomgar-scc*
GOTO START
pause

:END
EXIT
```

---

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am understanding your requirements but maybe not.  I have commented the code to let you know what it is doing.

```
@echo off
REM For command will attempt to find all folders
REM that start with bomgar-scc in the programdata folder
for /d %%G IN ("%programdata%\bomgar-scc*") do (
    REM If it finds a folder check if an uninstall.bat
    REM exists and run the batch file if it does exist.
    IF EXIST "%%~G\uninstall.bat" CALL "%%~G\uninstall.bat"
    REM Remove the directory found
    rd "%%~G"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Jump client MSI installer. Run the following command to uninstall it.**

> msiexec.exe /x "\%networkpath%\bomgar-scc-win64.msi" /quiet